# App Engine - How to set "Vary: Accept-Encoding" header for static files

Tags: google-app-engine

Google Page Speed says.

> The following publicly cacheable, compressible resources should have a "Vary: Accept-Encoding" header:

for my css and js files.

How can I set google app engine to do this?

Comment: For everyone who would like to see this implemented please star this issue http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3442

Comment: @x64igor Isn't headers for static files what you are asking for? This is possible since 1.7.0: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_Directory_Handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google App Engine tries to serve [compressed content](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#compression) when it can. So you shouldn't have to do anything as long as the client follows the guidelines at the link.

Comment: `Vary: Accept-Encoding` tells proxies how the resource should be cached. From http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html#LeverageProxyCaching - This instructs the proxies to cache two versions of the resource: one compressed, and one uncompressed. The correct version of the resource is delivered based on the client request header.

Comment: You really don't have any control over how App Engine serves static content. They just do it for you. I think it's pretty safe to assume they're going to follow most of the same best practices they advise for others.

Comment: @drew you do have some control, you can specify browser cache expirations: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files . And currently they are not setting the `vary: accept-encoding` header as page speed says to.

Comment: And now you can even specify `http_headers:` `Vary: Accept-Encoding` for statics: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers

Answer (score 4):

From [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers), just add the http_headers for the handlers you need in app.yaml (for Python):

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  http_headers:
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Answer (score 0):

The return headers for static content can be set while using the Python language in GAE. Details here: [Static Directory Handlers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_Directory_Handlers)